# Weird disk usage statistics

Tags: 20.04, disk-usage

When I use `df -h` it shows:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdg5       218G  151G   56G  74% /
```

Which correct capacity according to `lsblk`

```
sdg      8:96   1 223,6G  0 disk 
├─sdg1   8:97   1   1,9G  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdg2   8:98   1     1K  0 part 
└─sdg5   8:101  1 221,7G  0 part /
```

But when I use `du -h --max-depth 2 | grep G` it shows similar result as `sudo baobab`

```
36G     /home/kyz
11G     /home/kcy
47G     /home
11G     /usr
13G     /var/lib
22G     /var
8,2G    /snap
```

which the totals should be only using around 100 GB (detected only 87 GB in baobab probably because of `/snap` directory should not counted), where is my other 51 GB disk usage gone into?

[image: sudo baobab result]

**EDIT1** Tried one solution on the answer, seems the same:

```
sudo mount -o bind / /mnt
du -hs /mnt
# 80 GB
```

**EDIT2** Tried another solution from the answer, only few megabytes locked (total less than 2 GB) for deletion:

```
sudo lsof | grep deleted
chrome     463364  485536 MemoryInf           kcy  txt       REG              8,101   167169112   11273579 /opt/google/chrome/chrome (deleted)
chrome     463364  485536 MemoryInf           kcy    5r      REG              8,101    10518160   11273640 /opt/google/chrome/icudtl.dat (deleted)
MainThrea  729751                                kyz   14r      REG              8,101    25411839    7085195 /usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja (deleted)
MainThrea  729751                                kyz   15r      REG              8,101    43682061    7085151 /usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja (deleted)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this issue tends to create numerous duplicates over the stackexchange network. Here is the direct link to the approved solution:

https://serverfault.com/questions/275206/disk-full-du-tells-different-how-to-further-investigate

but you should be able to find more by googling "du vs df mounted disks".

Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

Found the culprit, it was `yakuake` for my case, the scroll log was way too large (11GB -- `journalctl -f` and 34GB -- `ktorrent`), reseting the scrollback (or setting it low 32k for example, solves this issue)

found by typing this command: `lsof -Pn +L1` (this is way faster than any other `lsof` command I found on another stackexchange [sites](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382693/how-to-find-the-largest-open-files)).

The full command for checking:

```
lsof -Pn +L1 2> /dev/null | 
awk '{if ($NF=="(deleted)") {x=4;y=1} else {x=2;y=0}; {print $(NF-x) "  " $(NF-y) } }' | 
sort -nru | 
numfmt --field=1 --to=iec
```